# Display live data from Battery Management System

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have a problem displaying the content of a message from a Battery management System (EMUS BMS) in Tkinter. I use a Raspberry-Pi 4 to collect the data via Serial, then parse the data through elif conditions and log the data on a usb stick.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.font as font
import serial
import time
from USB_Status import usb_status
import threading, queue

class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets(master)

    def create_widgets(self, master):

        def button_emus():
            anweisungs_label.config(text="EMUS BMS ausgewählt!", fg="green")
            q = queue.Queue()
            thread_ = threading.Thread(
                            target=connection_emus, 
                            name="Emus-Thread",
                            args=[q],
                            daemon=True,
                            )
            thread_.start()
            thread_.join()
            text_box.insert("end-1c", q.get())

        emus_button.place(x = 420, y = 0, width=400, height=150)
        text_box.place(x = 0, y = 160, width=2048, height=800)    

def verarbeitung_emus(response, binary):
    telegram=[]

    #Battery Voltage Summary Sentence
    if response[0:3] == "BV1":
        number_of_cells = str(int(response[4:8], 16)) + " Zellen"
        binary.write((number_of_cells + "\n").encode())

        min_cell_voltage ="min. " + str((int(response[9:11], 16) + 200) * 0.01) + " V"
        binary.write((min_cell_voltage + "\n").encode())

        max_cell_voltage ="max. " + str((int(response[12:14], 16) + 200) * 0.01) + " V"
        binary.write((max_cell_voltage + "\n").encode())

        number = (int(response[15:17], 16) + 200) * 0.01
        average_cell_voltage = "avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
        binary.write((average_cell_voltage + "\n").encode())

        telegram.extend([number_of_cells, min_cell_voltage, max_cell_voltage, average_cell_voltage])

    # Battery Cell Module Temperature Summary Sentence
    elif response[0:3] == "BT1":

        number = int(response[9:11], 16) - 100
        if number > 32767:
            number = number - 65536
        min_cell_module_temp = "min. " + str(number) + " °C"
        binary.write((min_cell_module_temp + "\n").encode())

        number = int(response[12:14], 16) - 100
        if number > 32767:
            number = number - 65536
        max_cell_module_temp = "max. " + str(number) + " °C"
        binary.write((max_cell_module_temp + "\n").encode())

        number = int(response[15:17], 16) - 100
        if number > 32767:
            number = number - 65536
        average_cell_module_temp = "avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " °C"
        binary.write((average_cell_module_temp + "\n").encode())

        telegram.extend([min_cell_module_temp, max_cell_module_temp, average_cell_module_temp])



    # Battery Balancing Rate Summary Sentence
    elif response[0:3] == "BB1":

        min_balancing_rate = "min. " + str(int(response[9:11], 16) * 100/255) + " %"
        binary.write((min_balancing_rate + "\n").encode())

        max_balancing_rate = "max. " + str(int(response[12:14], 16) * 100/255) + " %"
        binary.write((max_balancing_rate + "\n").encode())

        number = int(response[15:17], 16) * 100/255
        average_balancing_rate = "avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " %"
        binary.write((average_balancing_rate + "\n").encode())

        balancing_voltage_threshold = str((int(response[19:20], 16) + 200) * 0.01) + " V"
        binary.write((balancing_voltage_threshold + "\n").encode())


        telegram.extend([min_balancing_rate, max_balancing_rate, average_balancing_rate, balancing_voltage_threshold])

    #  “Current and Voltage” Sentence
    elif response[0:3] == "CV1":
        total_voltage = "overall " +  str((int(response[4:12], 16) + 200) * 0.01) + " V"
        binary.write((total_voltage + "\n").encode())

        number = int(response[13:17], 16) * 0.1
        if number > 32767:
            number = number - 65536
        current = "overall " +  str(format(number, '.2f')) + " A"
        binary.write((current + "\n").encode())

        telegram.extend([total_voltage, current])
    return telegram

def connection_emus(queue):
    DEVICE = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    BAUD = 57600
    ser = serial.Serial(DEVICE, BAUD)
    binary = open('/media/data_logger/EMUS.bin', "ab")

    try:
        while True:
            response = ser.readline()[:-2]
            response = response.decode()
            temp = verarbeitung_emus(response, binary)
            if temp:
                queue.put(temp)
                while not queue.empty():
                    print(queue.get())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        usb_status()
        ser.close()
        binary.close()

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I've tried out threading, to run the loop in the background and access it to read out the values, but I've never worked with threading and besides starting a thread I cannot access anything.

Edit: threading works now with the queue class, I can display the data from a daemon process. But now I want to pass the data to the textbox object in tkinter. Any suggestions how to achieve this ?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `threading.Thread(target=Emus)` instead of `threading.Thread(target=Emus())`

Comment: yes, you're right, I stil cannot access the data

Comment: You consume the queue just after putting data into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by breaking the while loop and avoid using the multiprocessing or threading libary.

```
import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import tkinter.font as font
    import serial
    import time
    from USB_Status import usb_status
    
    class Application(tk.Frame):
        
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.master = master
            self.pack()
            self.create_widgets(master)
    
        def create_widgets(self, master):
            
            def button_emus():
                anweisungs_label.config(text="EMUS BMS ausgewählt!", fg="green")
                antwort = self.connection_emus()
                [number_of_cells, min_cell_voltage, max_cell_voltage, average_cell_voltage] = antwort[0]
                [min_cell_module_temp, max_cell_module_temp, average_cell_module_temp] = antwort[1]
                [min_balancing_rate, max_balancing_rate, average_balancing_rate, balancing_voltage_threshold] = antwort[2]
                [total_voltage, current] = antwort[3]
    
                # = self.connection_emus()
                text_box.insert("end-1c", number_of_cells + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", min_cell_voltage + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", max_cell_voltage + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", average_cell_voltage + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", min_cell_module_temp + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", max_cell_module_temp + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", average_cell_module_temp + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", min_balancing_rate + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", max_balancing_rate + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", average_balancing_rate + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", balancing_voltage_threshold + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", total_voltage + "\n")
                text_box.insert("end-1c", current + "\n")
    
            emus_button = tk.Button(master, text="EMUS BMS", command=button_emus)
            exit_button = tk.Button(master, text="Beenden", command=master.quit)
            text_box = tk.Text(master)

            emus_button.place(x = 420, y = 0, width=400, height=150)  
            text_box.place(x = 0, y = 160, width=2048, height=600)    
            exit_button.place(x = 1500, y = 820, width=400, height=150)
    
        def verarbeitung_emus(self, response, binary):
            telegram=[]
    
            #Battery Voltage Summary Sentence
            if response[0:3] == "BV1":
                number_of_cells = format(int(response[4:8], 16), '.2f')
                #str(format(number, '.2f')) + " Zellen"
                binary.write(str(number_of_cells).encode())
    
                min_cell_voltage = format((int(response[9:11], 16) + 200) * 0.01, '.2f')
                #"min. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
                binary.write(str(min_cell_voltage).encode())
    
                max_cell_voltage = format((int(response[12:14], 16) + 200) * 0.01, '.2f')
                #"max. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
                binary.write(str(max_cell_voltage).encode())
    
                average_cell_voltage = format((int(response[15:17], 16) + 200) * 0.01, '.2f')
                #"avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
                binary.write(str(average_cell_voltage).encode())
    
                telegram.extend([number_of_cells, min_cell_voltage, max_cell_voltage, average_cell_voltage])
    
            # Battery Cell Module Temperature Summary Sentence
            elif response[0:3] == "BT1":
    
                number = int(response[9:11], 16) - 100
                if number > 32767:
                    number = number - 65536
                min_cell_module_temp = format(number, '.2f')
                #"min. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " °C"
                binary.write(str(min_cell_module_temp).encode())
    
                number = int(response[12:14], 16) - 100
                if number > 32767:
                    number = number - 65536
                max_cell_module_temp = format(number, '.2f')
                #"max. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " °C"
                binary.write(str(max_cell_module_temp).encode())
    
                number = int(response[15:17], 16) - 100
                if number > 32767:
                    number = number - 65536
                average_cell_module_temp = format(number, '.2f')
                #"avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " °C"
                binary.write(str(average_cell_module_temp).encode())
    
                telegram.extend([min_cell_module_temp, max_cell_module_temp, average_cell_module_temp])
    
  
    
            # Battery Balancing Rate Summary Sentence
            elif response[0:3] == "BB1":
                
                min_balancing_rate = format(int(response[9:11], 16) * 100/255, '.2f')
                #"min. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " %"
                binary.write(str(min_balancing_rate).encode())
    
                max_balancing_rate = format(int(response[12:14], 16) * 100/255, '.2f')
                #"max. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " %"
                binary.write(str(max_balancing_rate).encode())
    
                average_balancing_rate = format(int(response[15:17], 16) * 100/255, '.2f')
                #"avrg. " + str(format(number, '.2f')) + " %"
                binary.write(str(max_balancing_rate).encode())
    
                balancing_voltage_threshold = format((int(response[19:20], 16) + 200) * 0.01, '.2f')
                #str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
                binary.write(str(balancing_voltage_threshold).encode())
                
                telegram.extend([min_balancing_rate, max_balancing_rate, average_balancing_rate, balancing_voltage_threshold])
    
            #  “Current and Voltage” Sentence
            elif response[0:3] == "CV1":
                total_voltage = format((int(response[4:12], 16) + 200) * 0.01, '.2f')
                #"overall " +  str(format(number, '.2f')) + " V"
                binary.write(str(total_voltage).encode())
    
                number = int(response[13:17], 16) * 0.1
                if number > 32767:
                    number = number - 65536
                current = format(number, '.2f')
                #"overall " +  str(format(number, '.2f')) + " A"
                binary.write(str(current).encode())
    
                telegram.extend([total_voltage, current])
    
            if telegram:
                print(telegram)
                return telegram
    
        def connection_emus(self):
            DEVICE = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
            BAUD = 57600
            ser = serial.Serial(DEVICE, BAUD)
            binary = open('/media/data_logger/EMUS.bin', "ab")
            temp = []
    
            while True:
                response = ser.readline()[:-2]
                response = response.decode()
                if response[0:3] == "CV1" or response[0:3] == "BB1" or response[0:3] == "BT1" or response[0:3] == "BV1":
                    temp.append(self.verarbeitung_emus(response, binary))
                    print(temp)
                if response[0:3] == "CV1":
                    usb_status()
                    ser.close()
                    binary.close()
                    break
            if response[0:3] == "CV1":
                return temp
    '''
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                usb_status()
                ser.close()  
                binary.close()
                '''
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```